# How to select a group which have maximum date

Tags: oracle, group-by, max

I have this table :

[image]

I want to count the number of WKF_NDI which have the same EQUIPMENT and max(DATE_RECEIPT).

I try :

```
select EQUIPMENT,DATE_RECEIPT,COUNT(WKF_NDI) from CMM_DB.REF_WKF_THEMIS_H323
where date_receipt in ( select max(date_receipt)from CMM_DB.REF_WKF_THEMIS_H323)
group by EQUIPMENT, DATE_RECEIPT;
```

Result :

[image]

The output is just one line.

I want the output like this :

```
PF2_SBAA-B  28/12/17 10:00:01,000000000 5
PF2_SBCC-D  27/12/17 16:50:01,000000000 5
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-query just selects the maximum `date-receipt` so your main query will only select records which match that date. It seems you want to select the maximum date for each piece of equipment.

If so, you need to amend the sub-query accordingly:

```
select EQUIPMENT,DATE_RECEIPT,COUNT(WKF_NDI) 
from CMM_DB.REF_WKF_THEMIS_H323
where (EQUIPMENT,date_receipt) in ( select EQUIPMENT, max(date_receipt)
                                    from CMM_DB.REF_WKF_THEMIS_H323
                                    group by EQUIPMENT)
group by EQUIPMENT, DATE_RECEIPT;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible without sub-query (thus may perform better) when you use [FIRST/LAST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) function:

```
SELECT MAX(EQUIPMENT) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY DATE_RECEIPT) as EQUIPMENT, 
    MAX(DATE_RECEIPT), 
    COUNT(WKF_NDI) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY DATE_RECEIPT) 
FROM REF_WKF_THEMIS_H323
GROUP BY EQUIPMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the maximum date, partitioned by equipment, using an over clause places that value on each row thus it becomes a simple where clause to choose the rows matching that date:

```
SELECT
      EQUIPMENT
    , DATE_RECEIPT
    , COUNT(WKF_NDI)
FROM (
      SELECT
            EQUIPMENT
          , DATE_RECEIPT
          , MAX(date_receipt) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIPMENT) max_date
      FROM CMM_DB.REF_WKF_THEMIS_H323
      ) d
WHERE DATE_RECEIPT = max_date
GROUP BY
      EQUIPMENT
    , DATE_RECEIPT;
```